# Which TeX distribution or software?

Tags: windows, sharelatex

I work on Windows. Lately, I have been using a lot of LaTeX and I ShareLaTeX is not available to me. I want an offline software for Windows.  Now I know that there are many, but which is the best to go for? please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer WinEdt. I like the interface and have never had any issues with it!

http://www.winedt.com/news.html